# Update column(name) values with fake names from any random database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has 3500 records as of now and the records are being added each day. The table has various columns which include Last Name, Middle Name, First Name etc. I need to change these names (First, Last and Middle) to some random values for privacy reasons.

For random names I am thinking of using any random database which has random names. Where could I get a list of random names that I could use it for updating my table?

I am thinking of using "mockaroo" which generates a list of random names in CSV format and the importing it into SQL Server to make the changes. Is this a good way to go ahead?

Any help in this direction would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just delete the columns? If you're just putting nonsense data in the fields, why bother keeping the fields at all?

Comment: @Robbert I have edited the post. Sorry for the wrong question.

Comment: We anonymise massive SQL dbs with lists of names, cities from free online source such as http://www.babycenter.com/top-baby-names-2013 for first names etc. Or lists of company addresses or whatever. Is this what you're talking about? we just load the data, determine numbers of changes needed (running distinct queries) and then run scripts to update the data.

Comment: Yes @PreetSangha. I am talking about this only. I am using "mockaroo" which is generating all the names in CSV format. So after do i just need to import the file in SQL server and run update statements?

Comment: I suppose so - it's all just data but you need to be consistent if the text is in any of the keys.